# Is there a way to connect to a SignalR hub using server and by using current session for authentication?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I am trying to implement connect to a SignalR hub using C# not JavaScript. I want to connect to the hub and invoke some methods on the hub.

I am able to create the connection like this

```
var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
.WithUrl("https://currentsite.com")
.Build();

await connection.InvokeAsync("test");

....
```

The problem is that the hub require authentication. The question, is there a way to connect to the hub (on the same app) using the current authenticated session?

Comment: Is this SignalR for ASP.NET 4.x - or for ASP.NET Core?

Comment: What do you mean by "current authenticated session", exactly? I assume you're referring to ASP.NET's own authX cookies - but those are intended for use only by browser-based users/clients, not C# (headless?) clients.

Comment: @Dai ASP.NET Core. yes I mean to use the current identity used. The hub and the client are executed on the same server (a controller is calling the hub using a client)

Comment: ...in practice, in a modern (ASP.NET Core-era) SignalR scenario, the C# clients will authenticate using a non-cookies-based approach (typically a Bearer Token like a JWT issued by the ASP.NET Core application itself - or a separate IdP service; but could also use Client Certificates too). In this approach, there are opportunities for an already-authenticated cookies-in-browser-based human user to "adopt" or _delegate_ their authorization to a headless, non-human, bearer-token C# client - but it's a complex topic and your post is lacking in crucial details...

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "current identity used"

Comment: when the user connect to the app amd access the controller that would create a new instance of the `HubConnectionBuilder` would be already authenticated by asp.net. The user will have identity in the app. I want to be able to share the same identity session with the Hub so that the ``Authorize` attribute would not return 401

Comment: **How** is the user connecting to your (web-)app - and how are they authenticating, exactly? Assuming it's using a bearer-token, why can't you simply pass the token along?

Comment: @Dai the app user cookie authentication. An I able to generate a token and pass it to the hub?

Comment: ...how is your application using cookie authentication? Cookies are meant to be used only by web-browsers, not other kinds of clients.

Comment: Depends on how the signal is being hosted...is it in framework or net? Is it self-hosted? You can use a c# client to connect to the hub and pass in the access token inside your .build() method. How you handle it inside SignalR depends on the setup.